# Does function NTILE exist in JDV

Tags: redhat-datavirt

I am trying to work with percentiles in Teiid, but I get the following error

> Query execution failed
>   Reason:
>   SQL Error [30068] [50000]: TEIID30068 Remote org.teiid.api.exception.query.QueryResolverException: TEIID30068 The function 'ntile(ALL 100)' is an unknown form.  Check that the function name and number of arguments is correct.

The query I am using is:

```
   SELECT  id, zip5, 
     ntile(100) OVER(ORDER BY geopgraphy) as percentile
   FROM svi2105_us_zip5.svi2015_us_zip5;
```

Any ideas how to use this or any other similar functions?

Answer (score 0):

Not currently as of Teiid 11.0, but can log JIRA [1] for NTILE support.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/projects/TEIID/issues

Comment: is that the same for PERCENTILE_CONT ?

Comment: You can check for all the function support for Teiid here http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/Scalar_Functions.html